# Dynamic function call from generics depending on type

Tags: go, generics

Is it possible to use generics to call a function depending on the type of parameters?
I will try to explain my task in as much detail as possible.

For example, I have a structure with two methods:

```golang
package main

import "reflect"

type Cut interface {
    int | int8 | int16 | int32 | int64 | float32 | float64 | string
}

type AudioObj struct {
    fileName string
}

func (A AudioObj) CutIfFirstIsString(from string, to float64) {
    // Cut audio file: ("00:00:03", 81.0)
}

func (A AudioObj) CutIfSecondIsString(from float64, to string) {
    // Cut audio file: (0.3, "01:21:00")
}
```

#### And this is my generic:

```golang
func CutAudio[S Cut, E Cut](MusicFile AudioObj, start S, end E) {
    // The first parameter is a string.
    if reflect.ValueOf(start).Kind() == reflect.String {
        MusicFile.CutIfFirstIsString(start, end)
    }

    // The second parameter is a string.
    if reflect.ValueOf(end).Kind() == reflect.String {
        MusicFile.CutIfSecondIsString(start, end)
    }
}
```

Here I try to cut the audio file depending on function parameters type:

```golang
func main() {
    audio := AudioObj{fileName: "music.mp3"}

    CutAudio(audio, "00:00:03", 81.0)
    CutAudio(audio, 0.3, "01:21:00")
}
```

Output:

```sh
./prog.go:24:32: cannot use start (variable of type S constrained by Cut) as type string in argument to MusicFile.CutIfFirstIsString
./prog.go:24:39: cannot use end (variable of type E constrained by Cut) as type float64 in argument to MusicFile.CutIfFirstIsString
./prog.go:29:33: cannot use start (variable of type S constrained by Cut) as type float64 in argument to MusicFile.CutIfSecondIsString
./prog.go:29:40: cannot use end (variable of type E constrained by Cut) as type string in argument to MusicFile.CutIfSecondIsString
```

**PlayGround**: https://go.dev/play/p/1jx1-vHXDdn

It is posibile to convert generic type into the type that I sended to it?

Comment: I think it's not a good example to use generics. Code will be easier if you just will use float and convert it. Because you should converrt it anyways at the end.  

func CutAudio(MusicFile AudioObj, start, end float).

And just use it CutAudio(audio, toSeconds("00:00:03"), 81.0)

https://go.dev/blog/when-generics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a good old type switch, but it is a little bit verbose:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type Cut interface {
    int | int8 | int16 | int32 | int64 | float32 | float64 | string
}

type AudioObj struct {
    fileName string
}

func (A AudioObj) CutIfFirstIsString(from string, to float64) {
    // Cut audio file: ("00:00:03", 81.0)
    fmt.Println(`Cut audio file: ("00:00:03", 81.0)`)
}

func (A AudioObj) CutIfSecondIsString(from float64, to string) {
    // Cut audio file: (0.3, "01:21:00")
    fmt.Println(`Cut audio file: (0.3, "01:21:00")`)
}

func CutAudio[S Cut, E Cut](MusicFile AudioObj, start S, end E) {
    // The first parameter is a string.
    if _, ok := any(start).(string); ok {
        MusicFile.CutIfFirstIsString(cutToString(start), cutToFloat(end))
    }

    // The second parameter is a string.
    if _, ok := any(end).(string); ok {
        MusicFile.CutIfSecondIsString(cutToFloat(start), cutToString(end))
    }
}

func cutToString[S Cut](cut S) string {
    var str string
    switch start := any(cut).(type) {
    case int:
        str = strconv.FormatInt(int64(start), 10)
    case int8:
        str = strconv.FormatInt(int64(start), 10)
    case int16:
        str = strconv.FormatInt(int64(start), 10)
    case int32:
        str = strconv.FormatInt(int64(start), 10)
    case int64:
        str = strconv.FormatInt(start, 10)
    case float32:
        str = strconv.FormatFloat(float64(start), 'G', -1, 32)
    case float64:
        str = strconv.FormatFloat(start, 'G', -1, 64)
    case string:
        str = start
    }

    return str
}

func cutToFloat[S Cut](cut S) float64 {
    var flt float64
    switch end := any(cut).(type) {
    case int:
        flt = float64(end)
    case int8:
        flt = float64(end)
    case int16:
        flt = float64(end)
    case int32:
        flt = float64(end)
    case int64:
        flt = float64(end)
    case float32:
        flt = float64(end)
    case float64:
        flt = end
    case string:
        flt, _ = strconv.ParseFloat(end, 64)
    }
    return flt
}

func main() {
    audio := AudioObj{fileName: "music.mp3"}

    CutAudio(audio, "00:00:03", 81.0)
    CutAudio(audio, 0.3, "01:21:00")
}
```

[Playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/qoHkKWBJutX)